2 sets of 4 words
What do these words have in common? There needs to be two sets of four words. lace, ant, driver, scott, heel, sole, west,tongue

Welcome to PSE (Puzzling Stack Exchange)!

Welcome to Puzzling, take our [tour]! Could you please provide proper attribution for this question?

The first group was easy to identify

 Lace, heel, sole and tongue are part of a shoe

To be honest, I had no idea for the other groupm so I had to google it and found a NYT connections solution with the exact same word, so

 Ant, Driver, Scott and West are all Adams.

And of the four, I only knew the last one.
